# ACL в Mojolicious

Tags: mojolicious, perl

Хочу реализовать доступ к определённым действиям (action) открытым только для определённых пользователей (admin,moderator,user) , как это сделать более правильно ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данный момент это решается посредством *under*. Вот пример из документации:

```
# /blackjack -> {cb => sub {...}}
#               {controller => 'hideout', action => 'blackjack'}
my $auth = $r->under('/' => sub {
  my $c = shift;

  # Authenticated
  return 1 if $c->req->headers->header('X-Bender');

  # Not authenticated
  $c->render(text => "You're not Bender.", status => 401);
  return undef;
});
$auth->get('/blackjack')->to('hideout#blackjack');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё как вариант можно использовать under, как для примера это реализовано в [Galileo](https://github.com/keedi/Galileo/blob/master/lib/Galileo.pm). На этом варианте я и остановился кстати